# I run a Qt C++ project in Visual studio and got "the program can not start because QtCored4.dll" is missing

Tags: c++, qt

I am running a Qt C++ Project in Visual Studio 2008 and I got this error message:

```
"The program can't start because QtCored.dll is missing from your computer. Try installing the program to fix this problem".
```

Then I copy: QtCored4.dll from C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin to the exe program

I run it again, I got:

```
"The program can't start because QtGuid4.dll is missing from your computer. Try installing the program to fix this problem".
```

Then I copy: QtGuid4.dll from C:\Qt\4.8.0\bin to the exe program

Then I run it again, I got:

```
"the application was unable to start correctly (0xc015002). Click OK to close the program.
```

Then I check the Event Viewer, I see this:

> Activation context generation failed for "D:\rest\rrpT.exe". Dependent
>   Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

First of all, it is very strange to me because I am building and debugging the application on VS2008 but it asks for the dll files form VS2005. Then I copied those files from VS2005:

msvcm80d.dll - msvcp80d.dll - msvcr80d.dll

to the program folder but it is still the same error :(

And I think there is also something interesting:

```
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Bin\QtSolutions_PropertyBrowser-2.5d.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

why is that PropertyBrowser is dependent on VS2005?

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the side-by-side (SxStrace) utility mentioned? The message obviously thinks you can get a better error from that, so it's worth a shot.

Comment: I tried the sxstrace but parsing gave error. I check the event log and found the information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your copy of Qt was compiled with VS2005, thus it probably has a dependency on the version 8 runtime DLLs.  But your application is built with VS2008 and thus has a dependency on the version 9 runtime DLLs.  In general, you can't get both versions of the runtime DLLs into one process.  VC++ tends to break binary compatibility between major versions.

You need to recompile your own copies of the Qt DLLs with VS2008 or develop your application with VS2005.

Comment: FWIW, I've never had to recompile the QT dlls to work with VS2008.  In fact the QT downloads page only has vs2008 libraries, not vs2005 http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Comment: I have added some more issues. would it be the cause of VS2005?